# Разъяснить как работает метод по выходу из приложения

Tags: android, методы

Не хочется просто реализовать лишь бы реализовать, хочу разобраться.

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По шагам:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
```

Будет вызван системой, когда пользователь нажмёт назад.

```
if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
```

Здесь `back_pressed` - сохраненное время предыдущего нажатия кнопки назад (в миллисекундах). `System.currentTimeMillis()` - метод получения текущего времени в миллисекундах.

```
if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

То есть это означает "если с предыдущего нажатия кнопки назад прошло меньше 2-ух секунд, тогда выйти".

```
else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Если прошло больше 2-ух секунд с предыдущего нажатия, то напоминаем пользователю, что для выхода нужно нажать дважды.

```
back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Ну и обновляем время последнего нажатия.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ